# How can I get the info in cmd when I set ADB_TRACE=adb

Tags: python, cmd, adb, environment

I tried to get the progress when pushing a file to device.
It works when I "set ADB_TRACE=adb" in cmd (found in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595374/adb-push-pull-with-progress-bar))

Then I want to use it in python 2.7.

```
cmd = "adb push file /mnt/sdcard/file"
os.putenv('ADB_TRACE', 'adb')
os.popen(cmd)
print cmd.read()
```

It shows nothing.
How can I get these details?

OS:win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.popen#os.popen) is deprecated:

> Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the
>   `subprocess` module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with
>   the `subprocess` Module section.

Use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead:

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = ["adb","push","file","/mnt/sdcard/file"]
mysp = sp.popen(cmd, env={'ADB_TRACE':'adb'}, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = mysp.communicate()

if mysp.returncode != 0:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```

Comment: thanks, i got the details, but the command does't work find.I got some "could not create socket" errors

Comment: You're most welcome. Since you have the Python side taken care of, you might consider creating another question asking about the errors coming from `adb` command.