# how to get "adb device" to work when using Popen() with env

Tags: python, subprocess, adb, popen

the original code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779146/how-can-i-get-the-info-in-cmd-when-i-set-adb-trace-adb/)

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = ["adb","push","file","/mnt/sdcard/file"]
mysp = sp.popen(cmd, env={'ADB_TRACE':'adb'}, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = mysp.communicate()

if mysp.returncode != 0:
    print stderr
else:
    print stdout
```

it works fine without `env={'ADB_TRACE':'adb'}`.

exec any command about `adb` with the env variable, i got an error:

```
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

it seems not to work after kill the adb server

the whole output is [here](http://pastebin.com/CxbByGDW)

OS:win7

Comment: Does it work if you set `ADB_TRACE` and run `adb` via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect adb also needs other environment variables (like `$HOME`).
You should clone your existing environment and add `ADB_TRACE` to it.

```
import os
new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env['ADB_TRACE'] = 'adb'

# sp.popen()
```

From the docs:

```
If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment variables
for the new process; these are used instead of inheriting the current process’
environment, which is the default behavior.
```

Edit:

It seems, it's not about the envoronment itself.
Rather the adb server is broken if `ADB_TRACE` is set.
Try to start the server beforehand in an environment without `ADB_TRACE`.