# Batch file equivalent of PIPESTATUS

Tags: batch-file, pipe

In bash scripts, we can find the exit status of individual commands, which are piped to each other.
e.g. in below pseudo code:

```
 $ command1 | command2 | command3
```

The exit status of `command1`, `command2` & `command3` can be obtained in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`, `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` & `${PIPESTATUS[2]}` respectively.

Also, the exit status of last command (`command3` in this case) can be obtained from `$?`.

In case of windows batch scripts, we can find the exit status of the last command with `%ERRORLEVEL%`. Thus I would say, nearest equivalent of `$?` in batch scripting is `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

What is the equivalent of `PIPESTATUS` in batch scripting? How to find the exit status of individual commands?

Comment: google gave results only related to `bash` & I could not find related answer on `SO` also.

Comment: See [Windows command interpreter: how to obtain exit code of first piped command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11170753/1012053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe, that there is a direct way for this, but you could write a helper batch file for this.

**pipe.bat**

```
@echo off
set pipeNo=%1
shift
call %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
> piperesult%pipeNo%.tmp echo %errorlevel%
```

Then you could call it via

```
pipe 1 command1 | pipe 2 command2 | pipe 3 command3
```

This creates three files `piperesult<n>.txt` with the result for the commands.

Comment: Accepting this solution, because this seems to solve my requirement.. Thanks.

Comment: +1, but script will not work if command is a batch file. A pipeCall script that uses CALL is required, or else a single pipe script that uses/does not use CALL, depending on presence or absence of a /CALL option.

Comment: @dbenham Good point, and simple to solve by using always `CALL`. Btw. Do you see a possibility for auto numbering the pipeResults?

Answer (score 3):

No such animal. If you want the individual statuses, you'd need

```
command1 >tempfile
set status1=%errorlevel%
command2 <tempfile >anothertempfile
set status2=%errorlevel%
command3 <anothertempfile
set status3=%errorlevel%
```

Comment: Hmm... actually, the purpose of piping is to show a kind of progress bar, for first command. My current implementation is based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6680767/793796). I got the windows binaries of required commands, but I cannot tell, if first command has failed.

Comment: +1 This should be the normal solution, as it's simple and easily understandable