# What is a cross-platform compatible way to redirect to NUL or /dev/null?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, io-redirection

On Windows, one can use `> NUL` to redirect a pipe to nothing.  On Linux, one uses `> /dev/null`.  Is there a cross-platform compatible way to redirect a pipe to nothing for both platforms?  In other words, I would be able to use this and not worry about which platform the command is executing on.

For example, I would like to be able to write the following commands as one command.

```
echo Hello > NUL
echo Hello > /dev/null
```

Of course, anything more complicated would require separate scripts.  The use case is a single command being executed from cross-platform language (e.g. Java, Python).  I would like to avoid having to detect the platform and instead use a generic solution.

Furthermore, the use case is such that 100s of machines will be accessed and installing would be more complex than simply detecting the platform and adapting the command.

Comment: `if (windows) { > NUL } else { > /dev/null }`

Comment: I can't see how this can be much useful... It's not like this is the only difference between `sh` and `cmd.exe`, you'll have to write separated scripts anyway for anything that goes a tiny bit farther  "launch this command".

Comment: You could write a shell function / doskey macro that redirects appropriately, then do something like `tonull echo Hello`.  Matteo's point's solid though - this is hard to use for anything realistic.  You can get cygwin and run shell scripts on Windows.

Comment: @MatteoItalia This is the last thing I need to make my NPM script completely cross-platform (to suppress some loud logging). So yes this can be useful.

Comment: I think it is a good question, but unfortunately for us it seems the answer is there is no such cross-platform way ...  :(

Answer (score 2):

Write a simple C program which accepts all input from stdio and just ignores it.

Name your program something like `null` and put it in the `PATH` for your operating system.

Then, you can do:

```
echo Hello | null
```

The program is simple to write. It is a little more than "hello world".

Comment: Good idea.  The particular use case I am facing would require installing such a program on a lot of machines.

Comment: Great answer, cause this gave me the idea to redirect to `cd` like `echo hello | cd`. It will just print the current prompt, no command output, no errors, results in success exit code, and no need to install or write anything. Works in Windows and Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in running a command and (possibly) its return code, why not have the calling/parent application receive and just discard any input? It would generally involve setting up a pipe or stream (e.g. [for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5711084/507519)) and possibly a separate thread, but it should not be too complex.

It might help if you mentioned which command you are launching and why. Some commands on Unix-like systems, for example, have a special command line option that suppresses most of the output.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this question depends on the environment. You will have to depend on *something* to do this.

In the original question, execution from Python or Java was mentioned. Using a C program is mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438538/5428361) by [prushik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3529457/prushik) and [Remi Guan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5299236/remi-guan). I, myself, got to this question looking for an answer to use in a Makefile (on Windows).

All solutions work on Linux and Windows. They discard any output to stdout. Output to stderr will still be shown.

**Beware that the Python, Java and C solutions all use piping, which discards the exit code.** Retrieving the exit code is again OS dependent . See: [Batch file equivalent of PIPESTATUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795968/batch-file-equivalent-of-pipestatus)

The answers using Python, Java and C all use a program that does nothing. You don't need to actively discard the piped input, just doing nothing with it is enough

I think the Python solution is the most elegant, followed by Java, and C is the least elegant. Except if you're already in a Makefile of course.

## Python

When you have python installed you can simply do:

```bash
echo Hello | python -c ""
```

## Java

Java is a bit more involved. You need a minimal java program source in your working directory.

`nullpipe.java`

```java
class nullpipe {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```bash
echo Hello | java nullpipe.java
```

## C

The C solution follows the same principle as the Java solution, but this time you can't combine compilation and execution.

`nullpipe.c`

```c
int main(){}
```

Before execution you need to compile.

```bash
gcc nullpipe.c -o nullpipe
```

Then you can execute:

```bash
echo Hello | nullpipe
```

You might want remove `nullpipe` afterwards. The residual executable `nullpipe` is my reason to call this the least elegant solution.

## Makefile

I was running make on Windows and thought I needed to use `echo Hello > NUL`, as is normal in the Windows Command Shell. But as it turns out, make was executing my commands in a bash shell (although I started it from Windows Command Shell). So, both in Windows and Linux you can use.

```bash
echo Hello > /dev/null
```

> Sidenote:
> My version of make was installed using [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/). If your version of make behaves different, please let me know in the comments. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: PIping to _any_ command which ignores its input would do the same thing. `echo "moo" | cd`

Comment: @tripleee

Yes, that might be true for the current version of Windows and for a specific distribution or version on Linux. But `cd` was not created for this purpose. Its features might change and then you're screwed.


It wouldn't be my first time figuring out that some GNU tools behave differently in Alpine and Ubuntu.


`echo "moo" | cd` works, but I wouldn't consider it good practice.

Comment: Then the workaround might be `echo "" | true` or etc. (You will have to create your own Windows version of `true` but that's how living on Windows is. Save as `true.cmd` in your `PATH` a file containing `@exit 0`.)

Answer (score 0):

The [dev-null-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dev-null-cli) package abstracts this away for you in a cross-platform way. Add it to your devDependencies, and then you can write

```
echo Hello | dev-null
```